# How to pronounce RIPEMD-160?

Tags: terminology, ripemd

Do I pronounce it as a word or letter-by-letter, i.e., "R-I-P-E-M-D"?

Comment: ripe (as in "ripe for the picking") and MD (as in "Gregory House, M.D.). RipeMD!

Comment: /ɹaːɪp ɛm diː/${}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is pronounced *RIPE "tiny pause" M-D* (RIPE for RACE Integrity Primitives Evaluation and M-D for message digest).